# Why do I need to restart my PC with the physical button to get a display on the first boot?

Tags: boot, motherboard, windows-11

I recently assembled a PC that functions as expected, except for an issue when powering it on after a shutdown. Initially, the display doesn't appear, and I have to manually press the restart button on the case to prompt it. Once restarted, the "Asus" logo shows up.

An attempt to resolve this by disabling the Intel Integrated GPU in the BIOS has not been successful.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Does the display come on when booting the machine, showing the BIOS/UEFI screen? Or does no video appear until you push the restart button? The latter sounds like a communication issue on the video cable or a setting on the monitor.

Comment: @JW0914 It is the latter. I do not see the BIOS logo appear at all. After I press the reset button the monitor comes alive and shows the BIOS logo. I am connected using a HDMI cable I don't think there is an issue with the cable.